# Scheme Macros - Pair in the transform but list as output?

Tags: macros, scheme

Let's say I have the following macro in R<sup>5</sup>RS Scheme:

```
(define-syntax pair-test
  (syntax-rules ()
     ((_ (a b . c))
      (quote (a b . c)))))
```

The macro transforms an input pair to an output pair, as one would expect:

```
(pair-test (1 2 . 3))
==> (1 2 . 3)
```

I can also pass a list to the macro, as allowed by the spec. However, the output is a list instead of a pair:

```
(pair-test (1 2 3))
==> (1 2 3)
```

What exactly is going on here? Why is the output a list instead of a pair?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could `c` be `(3 . ())` in the second case? I'm not positive but that would make sense to me. And then quoting `(a b . c)` would be `(1 2 . (3 . ()))` which is `(1 2 . (3))` and `(3)` is a proper list, so `(1 2 3)`?

Comment: Yes. Actually, c is `(3 . ())`---the extra quote mark you have shouldn't be there---but you're essentially right.

Answer (score 2):

To see what's happening here, you need to know that a list in Scheme is a recursive chain of pairs of elements and other lists. Any data that follows the form of a list will always be printed as a list. Once you know how basic lists are constructed, you'll be able to see what's happening inside your macro.

Pairs in Scheme can be created using the `.` operator, or using the `cons` function. Here's a simple pair of numbers:

```
(quote (1 . 2))
==> '(1 . 2)
(cons 1 2)
==> '(1 . 2)
```

To create a list of 1 in Scheme, you can make a pair out of something and the empty list:

```
(quote (1 . ()))
==> '(1)
(cons 1 (list))
==> '(1)
```

A list of 2 is a pair of something of something on the left side, and a list of 1 on the right side. Likewise, a list of 3 is one element paired with a list of 2:

```
(quote (1 . (2 . (3 . ()))))
==> '(1 2 3)
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (list))))
==> '(1 2 3)
```

To see what your macro is doing, you can rearrange the `(quote (a b . c))` to be more explicit:

```
(quote (a . (b . c)))
(cons (quote a) (cons (quote b) (quote c)))
```

Now you can see that this form looks very similar to when you're constructing a list. If `(quote c)` results in a list, then the whole expression will be a list. In the case of `(pair-test (1 2 3))`, `c` becomes `(3 . ())`:

```
(quote (a . (b . c)))
==> (quote (1 . (2 . (3 . ()))))
==> '(1 2 3)
(cons (quote a) (cons (quote b) (quote c)))
==> (cons '1 (cons '2 '(3 . ())))
==> '(1 2 3)
```

This value is printed by the REPL as a list because it is a "proper list". Each right side (`cdr`) is a list, all the way up to the empty list at the end, so this value perfectly follows list form. The REPL assumes you'd like to see the result as a list, so it gets printed without a `.` present.

You'd see `'(1 2 . 3)` for `(pair-test (1 2 . 3))`, because this is how the REPL prints "improper lists". If the last element in the chain of pairs is not the empty list, the value is considered an "improper list", and will be printed differently:

```
(quote (1 . (2 . 3)))
==> '(1 2 . 3)
(cons 1 (cons 2 3))
==> '(1 2 . 3)
```